# How to make a Table record with View: header and row in scrollview not resize row view (image)

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

How to make a Table record with View: header and row in scrollview not resize row view (image)
I made a Table record with View: header and row. First both width columns of header and row equal with. But when row number go up, View contain my row will be inserted scrollbar, and width column of row does not equal width column of header. I used paddingRight to fix width column header again, but it sometimes run or not run. If i hide vertical scroll, my end user could not use scroll without mouse on web.
I used react native web (webpack) to design my project, so my project does not support jsx or react native table library.[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udSkW.png)
What must me do to fix width when insert vertical scroll. My code is here

```
<View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTable]}>
        <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableTopSc, { height: 40}]}>
            <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentHeaderRow, { height: 40 , paddingRight: apaddingRight  }]}>
                <View style={[GeneralStyle.viewCol15]}>
                    Column Header
                </View>
                <View style={[GeneralStyle.viewCol15]}>
                    Column Header .... n
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableMidSc]} >
            <ScrollView >
                <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewRowContentTable, { height: windowHeight - 190 }]}>
                            <View style={GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRow} key={item.RowID}>
                                <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRow, { borderWidth: 0 }]} key={item.RowID}>
                                    <View style={[GeneralStyle.viewCol15]}>
                                        row Column
                                    </View>
                                    <View style={[GeneralStyle.viewCol15]}>
                                        row Column .... n
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                    <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRowEmp, { height: 35 }]}></View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
</View>
```

How to make a Table record with View: header and row in scrollview not resize row view (image)